# "Magnanimous" auf Deutsch, und eine kleine Email

Tags: single-word-request, english-to-german

I would like to ask my work colleagues if they are interested in donating some portion of their time by participating in this fantastic site.

To that end, I wanted to write something tongue-in-cheek like:

"If you are feeling especially magnanimous today, then why not visit  and graciously donate some small percentage of your vast knowledge?"

in an e-mail.  It was then that I realised not only is my German not good enough to get across this kind of subtle humour without danger of it being offensive, but I can't even translate magnanimous.

So I ask: would grossherzig be a good word in this context for magnanimous?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

*"Großherzig"* is an appropriate translation but may not be widely used. Let me suggest  more commonly used alternatives:

> aufgeschlossen
>   uneigennützig
>   selbstlos

If however you intend to use a translation that is rarely used to make your friends curious then *"großherzig"* or any of the following may be better:

> weitherzig, hochherzig, honorig, edelmütig

Comment: +1, on the other hand: *magnanimous* isn't widely used either.

Comment: that's exactly why I put in the second paragraph ;P

Answer (score 4):

Yes,

> großherzig

is an appropriate translation.

Another possible translations is *großzügig*, but the it's more for a material context (donating money for example).

The word *edelmütig* and *großmütig* could also be used, but they're rather old fashioned.

Answer (score 1):

I also favor "großherzig". Magnanimous is derived from Latin "magna" (big, groß) and "anima" (heart, Herz).